# Is it ok if a package downgrades python?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, python.net

While installing Pythonnet using conda I find that it is downgrading couple of packages. Is it ok? How can I confirm it will not cause any other problems.

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
 openssl                                          3.0.7-0 --> 1.1.1n-0
 python                                           3.9.16-0 --> 3.9.11-2
```

Also, where can I find detailed requirement with versions list for Pythonnet.

Update: Got response from Python.Net -

> This can't have anything to do with Python.NET, we (and also the
> conda-forge package) place no restrictions on individual Python
> versions or openssl.

This make me wonder what is causing the change. Can anyone guide me how I could look for configurations where the dependencies and versions information is stored. How **conda** might be going about to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: It's common. Did you get a (red) message saying that package_X required openssl>3.9.11 ? If not I wouldn't worry.

Comment: No, there was not (red) message. Are you saying that conda ensures it will not break other existing package(s)?

Comment: It's doubtful that it's useful to downgrade to a previous *bugfix* version. I think that Pythonnet package is too harsh on its dependencies. It might be necessary, but I find it doubtful. Is there a specific Conda channel you install this from?

Comment: nope, The command I use is `conda install pythonnet`